# Programmatically Make First Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

How to Make any VC from Multiple VCs as a First Screen of My Application?
i have put Code in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching Mathod to make this possible.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
   [[Database shareDatabase]createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
    if ([self checkData])
    {
        VC1
    }
   else
   {
       VC2
   }


}

-(BOOL)checkData
{
    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"pin"] isEqualToString:nil])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return YES;
    }
}
```

is there any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can check this value on your vc1 viewwillappear, and present modal from your vc1, i guess you want a present a pin lock view controller. And after the check in vc2, you dismiss this one.

Comment: Actually i tried earlier as you say,but i've problem with that. in This scenario(as you told),first VC is Display and than it is go to Pin VC.

Comment: my point is,firstVC should not be display if already done with firstVC.